# Sum innertext VBA IE

Tags: excel, vba, internet-explorer

I got this several numbers that I would like to present the sum of rather then having to sum it up afterwards

```
MsgBox ie.document.getElementsByClassName("post_click_or_post_view_revenue")(0).innertext
MsgBox ie.document.getElementsByClassName("post_click_or_post_view_revenue")(1).innertext
MsgBox ie.document.getElementsByClassName("post_click_or_post_view_revenue")(2).innertext
MsgBox ie.document.getElementsByClassName("post_click_or_post_view_revenue")(3).innertext
```

I would like to do something like this instead

```
MsgBox Sum(ie.document.getElementsByClassName("post_click_or_post_view_revenue").innertext)
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to loop through the series of tags matching your class, converting the `.innerText` to an actual number (text that looks like a number if still not a number) as you progress through.

```
dim dTotal as double, l as long, e as long
with ie.document
    l = .getElementsByClassName("post_click_or_post_view_revenue").length - 1
    for e = 0 to l
        if isnumeric(trim(.getElementsByClassName("post_click_or_post_view_revenue")(e).innertext)) then _
            dTotal = dTotal + CDbl(.getElementsByClassName("post_click_or_post_view_revenue")(e).innertext)
    next e
end with
msgbox "The total is " & dTotal
```

Now that is going to loop through all of the elements with a matching class name. If you only want to go from 0 to 3 then use `for e = 0 to 3`. Just make sure there are actually four of them before you go into a loop asking for all four.

Comment: @NiklasAndersson - The `.innerText` have to at least *look* like numbers. You cannot try to `dTotal = dTotal + CDbl("abc")`. I've added a line of error control to avoid trying to convert an alphabetic string.

Comment: This is what I get when I MsgBox the first classnamn http://imgur.com/ADQ9DFa  Might it be the " . " the ruins it?

Comment: @NiklasAndersson - No, that should be fine. Leading/trailing spaces are OK but there may be leading/trailing non-breaking spaces (e.g. &nbsp; or &#160;)

Comment: Ran the entire thing again, works perfectly. It takes a while to come to this part. Sorry for my messup. I will just need to divided it by a million. And that is always fun. 

Thanks a lot man!

Comment: @NiklasAndersson - No worries. Glad to hear you got sorted out quickly.